# Why does my AC unit make the floor in the next room cold?

Tags: hvac

I live in a mobile home and when my central AC unit is running, the floor in the next room beside the unit, is very cold.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: It is a central hvac

Answer (score 2):

Do you like spiders and field mice?  *You do?* Great, you're gonna love this.

There are some pipes running underneath the trailer, between the air conditioning unit (ironically called the condenser) outside, and the air handler or mini-split inside your trailer (ironically called the evaporator even though it condenses water).

Those pipes are supposed to be wrapped with insulation.  I'm betting they're not anymore, as it has degraded or a mentally ill rodent made a meal of it. (clearly not the rat from *Ratatouille*.)   You would need to go on down there and have a looksy, and replace it with insulation from the building supply if so.

Comment: The names condenser and evaporator refer to their action on the refrigerant fluid inside them, not the substance (air or water) being cooled or heated. Naturally this is intuitive to HVAC people but backwards for anyone else!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like some duct work or possibly the floor joist are being used as duct work This would make the floor cold when running.

Comment: I've been in it 20 years and it just started within the last 6 months. Any suggestions how I might fix it?

Comment: Then something changed recently. What was it?

Comment: I really don't have a clue. I'm a widow and have no knowledge about this Kind Of Stuff!

Comment: Is the furnace / AC blower unit below the room? With an older unit that needs servicing the coil may be freezing up causing the problem. Or limited flow that is very cold.